# TypeError: props.articles.map is not a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have my app.js file and iam fetching the data from a backend REST API in my app.js file, after that iam sending the data to the child component ArticleList.js, the initial page is my Login.js page, iam adding my username and password to access the article list, but in the first time after the login iam receiving *TypeError: props.articles.map is not a function*, but when i refresh the page there is no error, i mean in the first attempt iam seeing that error, but when i refresh the page iam not seeing that error.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ArticleList from './components/ArticleList';
import ArticleDetails from './components/ArticleDetails'
import AddArticle from './components/AddArticle'
import {Route, Switch,BrowserRouter, useNavigate, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';



function App() {

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])

  //const navigate = useNavigate();

  const token = localStorage.getItem('mytoken')

  let navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
   
    fetch('https://testrest22.herokuapp.com/articles/', {
      method:'GET',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':`Token ${token}`
      }
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(resp => setArticles(resp))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))

   

  }, [token])


  useEffect(() => {
    if(!token) {
   
        navigate('/')
    }

}, [])

  const insertedArticle = (article) => {
    const new_articles = [...articles, article]
    setArticles(new_articles)
  }
  
 
return (

<>

<NavBar/>

<Routes>

    <Route path = "/" element = {<Login/>}></Route>

    <Route path   = "/articles"  element = {
       <div  className = "container mt-3"> 
       <ArticleList articles = {articles}/>
      </div>
       }>
     </Route>

   
     <Route path  = "/articles/:slug" element = {
        <ArticleDetails/>
      }>
    </Route>


    <Route path = "/add" element = {
        <AddArticle insertedArticle = {insertedArticle}/>
      }>
    </Route> 

</Routes>
   
               
</>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ArticleList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


function ArticleList(props) {

    return (
        <div>
            {props.articles && props.articles.map(article => {
                
        return(
            <div className = "mt-4" key = {article.slug}>
            <span className="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Author: {article.author}</span>
            <h2><Link to = {`/articles/${article.slug}`} className = "link-style" >{article.title}</Link></h2>
      
            <hr/>

        </div>
        )
      })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ArticleList
```

Comment: `.map()` can only be used with `array`. Maybe `articles` that you are getting after a `fetch` request is not an array. Can you paste ur fetched data.

Comment: This is the data in the console    (2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
author: "newuser"
description: "We can add new data in here, We can add new data in here, We can add new data in here, We can add new data in here, We can add new data in here, We can add new data in here,"
published: "December 19 2021"
slug: "this-is-the-newly-added-data"
title: "This is the newly added data"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Add exact output as per the console. It is not understandable.

Comment: the type is object, and iam fetching the data from django rest framework

Comment: If the state is not yet filled, `article` may not yet be iterable by `map`. You can fix it by setting the initial state to an empty array.

Comment: Habib could you add in your question an example of the feteched data ?

Comment: @Kokodoko which example, you mean the code from the backend api that is built in django rest framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{props?.articles[0] && props?.articles?.map(article => {
...
```

Comment: yea thanks this is working